# Passing and Using Dictionaries in Django Template Tags

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, django-templates

I have a function that uses the `psutil` library to fetch CPU usage data.

```
import psutil
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def get_cpu():
    """Gets the system-wide CPU utilisation percentage"""
    utilisation = list(psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1, percpu=True))
    cpu_data_utilisation = []
    load_avg_list = []
    cpu_data = {}
    for count in range(len(utilisation)):
        count = count + 1
        cpu_data_utilisation.append({
            "label" : str("CPU " + str(count)),
            "util" : round(utilisation[count-1])
        })
    load_avg_tuple = tuple(psutil.getloadavg())
    load_avg_1 = load_avg_tuple[0]
    load_avg_5 = load_avg_tuple[1]
    load_avg_15 = load_avg_tuple[2]
    load_avg_list.append({
        "1"  : round(load_avg_1),
        "5"  : round(load_avg_5),
        "15" : round(load_avg_15)
    })
    cpu_data = {
        "core_util" : cpu_data_utilisation,
        "load_avg"  : load_avg_list,
    }
    return cpu_data
```

I also have a template tag which calls and returns the `get_cpu` function.

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_cpu_data():
    return mark_safe(get_cpu())
```

In the HTML file, adding these two lines:

```
{% get_cpu_data as cpu_data %}
{{ cpu_data }}
```

Renders this:

```
{'core_util': [{'label': 'CPU 1', 'util': 66}, {'label': 'CPU 2', 'util': 21}, {'label': 'CPU 3', 'util': 62}, {'label': 'CPU 4', 'util': 22}, {'label': 'CPU 5', 'util': 56}, {'label': 'CPU 6', 'util': 22}, {'label': 'CPU 7', 'util': 54}, {'label': 'CPU 8', 'util': 23}], 'load_avg': [{'1': 5, '5': 5, '15': 4}]}
```

The dictionary has two keys, `core_util` and `load_avg`. I want to take the lists out of the values paired to the keys and iterate.

The template code below renders nothing.

```
{% for key, val in cpu_data.items %} 
    {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

But, this template code:

```
{% for data in cpu_data %} 
    {{ data }}
{% endfor %}
```

Returns this:

```
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    c
 
    o
 
    r
 
    e
 
    _
 
    u
 
    t
 
    i
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    [
 
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    l
 
    a
 
    b
 
    e
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    C
 
    P
 
    U
 
     
 
    1
 
    &#x27;
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    u
 
    t
 
    i
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    5
 
    0
 
    }
 
    ,
 
     
 
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    l
 
    a
 
    b
 
    e
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    C
 
    P
 
    U
 
     
 
    2
 
    &#x27;
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    u
 
    t
 
    i
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    1
 
    8
 
    }
 
    ,
 
     
 
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    l
 
    a
 
    b
 
    e
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    C
 
    P
 
    U
 
     
 
    3
 
    &#x27;
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    u
 
    t
 
    i
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    4
 
    3
 
    }
 
    ,
 
     
 
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    l
 
    a
 
    b
 
    e
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    C
 
    P
 
    U
 
     
 
    4
 
    &#x27;
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    u
 
    t
 
    i
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    1
 
    8
 
    }
 
    ,
 
     
 
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    l
 
    a
 
    b
 
    e
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    C
 
    P
 
    U
 
     
 
    5
 
    &#x27;
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    u
 
    t
 
    i
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    3
 
    8
 
    }
 
    ,
 
     
 
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    l
 
    a
 
    b
 
    e
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    C
 
    P
 
    U
 
     
 
    6
 
    &#x27;
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    u
 
    t
 
    i
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    2
 
    0
 
    }
 
    ,
 
     
 
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    l
 
    a
 
    b
 
    e
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    C
 
    P
 
    U
 
     
 
    7
 
    &#x27;
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    u
 
    t
 
    i
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    3
 
    5
 
    }
 
    ,
 
     
 
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    l
 
    a
 
    b
 
    e
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    C
 
    P
 
    U
 
     
 
    8
 
    &#x27;
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    u
 
    t
 
    i
 
    l
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    1
 
    8
 
    }
 
    ]
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    l
 
    o
 
    a
 
    d
 
    _
 
    a
 
    v
 
    g
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    [
 
    {
 
    &#x27;
 
    1
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    6
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    5
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    5
 
    ,
 
     
 
    &#x27;
 
    1
 
    5
 
    &#x27;
 
    :
 
     
 
    4
 
    }
 
    ]
 
    }
```

An extremely long unformatted string with one character in each line.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template tag you have the following line:

```
return mark_safe(get_cpu())
```

`mark_safe` returns a `SafeString` which is a subclass of `str`. Meaning what happens here is that your dictionary is converted to a string (actually instance of `SafeString`) which is marked as safe. Next when you try to loop over it may not actually be safe and hence it is *escaped* by the template engine. If you actually want to use it as a dictionary **don't** call `mark_safe` on it:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_cpu_data():
    return get_cpu()
```

Your use case might be that the *contents* of this dictionary is safe, which you can render as below if you want, or you can use `mark_safe` on the actual values of the dictionary:

```
{% for key, val in cpu_data.items %} 
    {{ key|safe }}: {{ val|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ```mark_safe``` was the issue, thanks for informing me. Without that, I am able to access the dictionary with even the key.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly related to the above problem, but this posts save me after two hours of hell, so I will point it out here for somebody similarly desperate in the future.

If you want to work with registered simple tag in your template, YOU MUST use this line first:

```
{% your_simple_tag_function_name as name_to_use_in_template %}
```

so as above specific example

```
{% get_cpu_data as cpu_data %}
```

If you don't do this and you will try to use directly your_simple_tag_function_name for any operation in template like looping etc., it will just not work. There is no mention about it in any Django docs at all!